# Where to set BackgroundColor of Monotouch.Dialog Element?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uicolor, monotouch.dialog

I am extending the StyledMultilineElement class to make a combination of RadioElement and StyledMultilineElement. The selection and combination of the two are working fine, however I my GetCell override seems to not properly set the background color of the cell.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (tv);

        bool selected = RadioIdx == this.rgroup.Selected;
        cell.Accessory = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        cell.BackgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.Cyan : UIColor.White;
        return cell;
    }
```

The checkmark does appear on the selected element telling me that the selected boolean is indeed correct, however the background color always appears as white.

I am assuming this is just because I am trying to do it in the GetCell method, but I'm not sure where else to put it.

So the question is, where would I set the BackgroundColor since it obviously isn't working here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the BackgroundColor property of the actual Element itself?

There are a few properties:

- `UITableViewCellAccessory Accessory`
- `int Lines`
- `UILineBreakMode LineBreakMode`
- `UIColor TextColor`
- `UIFont SubtitleFont`
- `UIFont Font`

These seem to be the area for setting the style.

Also, if the value of selected changes, the cell won't actually update right away. What you can do as well to refresh the cell is to call this when you want to refresh the cell:

```
RootElement root = GetImmediateRootElement ();
root.Reload (this, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
```

The `GetImmediateRootElement()` method is on the actual element.

references:
[MonoTouch.Dialog: Update of Text in an Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496462/monotouch-dialog-update-of-text-in-an-element)

Comment: I have the Selected method overridden to change the background color to Cyan and it works there. I'm asking where I should put my code, not what my code should be.

Comment: @spocot, the GetCell method is fine to set the background color. But, it should be the background of the element not the cell itself. Then you can just Reload in the select method.

Comment: so where should I do `cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan` then?

Comment: You do `Element.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan` in `GetCell`

Comment: The reason for this is that the `IColorizeBackground.WillDisplay` will override your colour of the cell.

Comment: Check out the source for MT.D (assembly browser) - `StyledStringElement.WillDisplay`